# Gnuplot shell script ROS data from multiple files

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot data from two different rosbag files using gnuplot. I'm trying to automate this as I have quite a few files that will need to be run.

I need to take the first element of the first column of each file and offset the data of the column w.r.t. that (and then divide by 10^9) to get the time in seconds. My issue is my script returns something different when I run it multiple times. It will either return the first, the second, or (occasionally) the third plot command, which is what I'm interested in.

The code I've cobbled together is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    set autoscale
    set datafile separator ","
    set key autotitle columnhead
    plot "bag1" using (\$1):2 with linespoints
    first=GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN
    plot "bag2" using (\$1):3 with linespoints
    second=GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN
    plot "bag1" using ((\$1-first)/10**9):2, "bag2" using ((\$1-second)/10**9):3
EOFMarker
```

An example of the dataset is:

```
%time,field.1,field.2,field.3
1.50317427276591E+018,23,64,64
1.50317427281556E+018,232,74,64
1.50317427285689E+018,216,76,64
1.50317427287325E+018,183,85,64
1.50317427292519E+018,165,89,64
1.50317427298662E+018,129,96,64
1.50317427300161E+018,115,101,64
1.50317427309547E+018,102,112,64
```

And the second input file is:

```
%time,field.1,field.2,field.3,field.4
1.50317425501603E+018,55,45,229,98755
1.50317425501843E+018,55,45,229,98752
1.5031742550235E+018,51,43,229,98758
1.50317425502979E+018,51,43,229,98761
1.50317425504176E+018,55,41,231,98764
1.50317425504579E+018,55,41,231,98770
1.50317425504728E+018,50,42,232,98773
1.50317425504855E+018,50,42,232,98773
1.50317425505353E+018,55,41,229,98770
1.50317425506442E+018,55,41,229,98770
```

I've never experienced code where multiple runs produces different results. Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this mess?
The outputs are the three plots below. No error message is output from the script at any time.

First output:

[image]

Third (and desired) output:

[image]

Comment: What is the different output that you get?

Comment: So I'm new to this, not sure I can post screenshots. But essentially twice it gives me the output of: "    plot "bag1" using (\$1):2 with linespoints", then once it gives me the output of "plot "bag2" using (\$1):3 with linespoints". And randomly it gives the third, "plot "bag1" using ((\$1-first)/10**9):2, "bag2" using ((\$1-second)/10**9):3"

Comment: you can embed the screenshots into your post, or just update your post with  the output in a code block

Comment: There isn't any output code, I've posted links to two of the graphs (don't have enough of a reputation to post more) and both sample files. I think I'll be trying to get matlab working with this, I'm now just curious why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are sometimes getting different results; I always get the output of the last `plot` command. However, you seem to be using the first two `plot` commands only to get the minimum value of the first column for each of the two files. A better way that doesn't generate any plots would be

```
set datafile separator ","
set key autotitle columnhead
stats "bag1" using 1
first=STATS_min
stats "bag2" using 1
second=STATS_min
plot "bag1" using (($1-first)/10**9):2, "bag2" using (($1-second)/10**9):3
```

Comment: I tried that code and it doesn't seem to work. In the end the first time it runs as a shell script it works fine, and so I can always just restart my shell. The other option is it works fine on the command line.